# Texture lookup vs handle attribute in shaders

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, opengl-es-2.0, gpu

My question is related to generating height maps with noise functions and others.

WebGL offers two interesting functions: `gl.texImage2D` and `gl.readPixels`. I would say they are kind of similar, first one uploads image data from canvas to the currently bound WebGLTexture, second fills Uint8Array buffer with the pixel data from canvas.

*Also as I understand, `gl.texImage2D` is almost identical as `gl.readPixels` if accepting different params.*

I have seen various (WebGL) height map implementations and as I remember all of them uses `texImage2D` and noone uses `readPixels`.

Lets say we have a plane made of vertices with [x, z] coordinates only and we are looking for y coordinate to distort our plane. So we can find the [y] coordinate via texture lookup and so we bind the texture to our program OR we could bind another buffer with data from canvas and read [y] as attribute.

> After thinking how texture lookup works and how attributes work,
>   texture lookup must be much more heavy compared to attribute? But how much?

*<--- this is my primary question related to how texture lookup works*

> But then I don't understand why people use textures so much?

*<--- In case first one is true, secondary question is about `gl.texImage2D` and `gl.readPixels`, how does it work from the point of javascript. Have you seen any demo with readPixels? Is there any advantage I don't see?*

Answer (score 1):

the difference between `texImage2D` / `texSubImage2D` and `readPixels` is that they do the exact opposite thing. One sends data to the gpu, the other reads that data back, which is (only) useful if you need that data in javascript.

As for the reason why people use textures for heightmaps instead of attributes is because it's easier to modify. It's a convenience, not a rule. If you want, you can implement it with attributes. Rendering it will most likely be slightly faster, modifying it will be much slower.

If you just want to load the terrain once, and never touch the data again, use attributes. If you want to modify it a lot, use textures.

I hope this answer is clearer. Didn't realize that it doesn't make that much sense to even attempt to explain the difference between textures and attributes to answer it.

Comment: Compare texSubImage2d and readPixels signature: 
`void texSubImage2D(GLenum target, GLint level, GLint xoffset, GLint yoffset, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type, ArrayBufferView? pixels)` and 
`void readPixels(GLint x, GLint y, GLsizei width, GLsizei height, GLenum format, GLenum type, ArrayBufferView? pixels)`
Do you insist they are opposites? `texImage2D` also reads data as unsigned int, except it creates buffer or fill texture. I don't want to modify data in javascript, the idea was simply why data are being passed as uniforms instead of attributes.

Comment: Im grateful for your answer. But after reading dozen things, I still dont get it... Im looking for "works really well together with a lot of other things"

Comment: @EntityBlack thanks for the feedback! I'm not really good at explaining those concepts yet I'm afraid. I have to see what I can simplify and where I have to go into the details. Is it better now?